# Update tbody datatable with ajax

Tags: php, jquery

this is I have a proablemn when update tboby from my datatable using ajax, this is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/zHcej/1/

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>User</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody_usr"></tbody>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tbody="<tr><td id='usrId_1'>Develop</td><td>dev</td></tr><tr><td id='usrId_2'>Tester</td><td>Test</td></tr>";
    $("#tbody_usr").html(tbody);
});
```

Comment: There is no ajax in this code sample.

Comment: Now I'm trying this:

    var tdata='{"aaData": [["Desarrollo","klo",],["Tester","123",]]}';
    $('#example').dataTable(tdata);

  But, doesn't work... sorry I'm new whit datatables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On datatables, you can use both Javascript array / ajax source as the table's data source.
take a look at these examples:

Javascript Array:
https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Ajax:
https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

EDIT:
try this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "aaData": [

            [ "Develop", "dev"],
            [ "Tester", "Test"]
        ]
    } );
```

EDIT2:
one of the external resources you've added in jsfiddle is initializing the datatable automatically!

remove the external initialization, or simply change your table's id to "example1"

and then do:

```
 $('#example1').dataTable( {
            "aaData": [

                [ "Develop", "dev"],
                [ "Tester", "Test"]
            ]
        } );
```

EDIT 3:

```
var tdata =  [[ "Develop", "dev"], [ "Tester", "Test"]];
 $('#example1').dataTable( {
                "aaData": tdata
            } );
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It works,justI change the id from the table. But other question, why I can't do this: var data="{'aaData':[['Desarrollo','klo','--'],['Tester','123','--'],]}";
$('#table').dataTable(data);

Comment: because I generate the var data with a for from ajax

Comment: Try to initialize your javascript var as an actual JS Array of Arrays, not as a json-string. i.e: var data = [['Desarrollo','klo','--'],['Tester','123','--']]; Good luck, hope this was helpful.

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful and I appreciate your time, but now when I set this In my page I get this err: datatables warning (table id= table_usr): requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0 , and the var tdata is showing all in the firts col

Comment: I was cheking and I think that is the type, because when I do the console.log(tdata) the type its a array, and when I generate the tdata by ajax it show me like a string. So how I can cast it?

Comment: It's actually ok for it to be an array. but let's do something more useful, post your code on jsfiddle and send me a link

Comment: A lot of thx, I just modified for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                tdata[tdata.length-1] = [data[i].name, data[i].user];
            } - to - for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                tdata[i] = [data[i].name, data[i].user];
            }